# Default Logic of conditional formatting icon sets

Tags: excel

I have the following cells in a excel file:

```
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
```

I am applying conditional formatting to include icon sets on each cell.  The default setting has three layers `>=67 percent`, `>= 33 percent` and <33 percent`.  When I use the first option of arrows, this fills the first three cells ie., upto 80 with up arrow, between 70 and 40 with a horizontal arrow and with down arrow for the other three.

On the contrary, instead of percent if I take percentile, excel ignores the last cell with value of 10.

What is the logic that excel uses to apply the icon sets.  Because I could not figure out why excel had not included the value 70 in the >= 67 percent and why it ignores when I take the percentile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `0` row.

[image]

In your original dataset, you're considering the range of *10 to 100*, not *0 to 100*. A range of 90 means that 70 falls at 66.67%.

Comment: does it mean excel considers both the number of cells and the magnitude of values in each cell?